# How to maintain the size of the cards and font size upon zooming out or in?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

My current screen is showing like this and I wanted to maintain the size of the cards and the font inside it, as shown image below [image]

But upon zooming in it become like the image below, it became elongated to the bottom, how to prevent it? [image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Reporting <br> Description Here </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="vr"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="align-self: center;">
          <h5 class="card-title">200</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Reporting <br> Description Here </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="vr"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="align-self: center;">
          <h5 class="card-title">200</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Reporting <br> Description Here </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="vr"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="align-self: center;">
          <h5 class="card-title">200</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Reporting <br> Description Here </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="vr"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="align-self: center;">
          <h5 class="card-title">200</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using inline styles, especially when there's a [class for that](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#align-self). If necessary, create a custom class.

Comment: It's not clear what outcome you're expecting. Developers generally don't concern themselves with extreme zoom, as it's a rare edge case and the site is still readable. What do you _want_ to happen in that case?

Comment: i am not sure how to do that on your first comment. i am expecting to get same view as the first picture if im zooming in regardless of different monitor size or resolution

Comment: That's not physically possible. You'd need your monitor to expand at the same rate. Something has to give.

Comment: is there any alternative?

Comment: you can use vh(Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport) or vw(Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport)